# What benchmark would test how well my hardware rates, for my ASP.NET, SQL Server, IIS product?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, configuration, windows-server-2003

What benchmark would test how well my hardware rates, for my ASP.NET, SQL Server, IIS product?

I have two servers, one runs my code much faster than the other and I believe their configurations are close to equivalent and therefore I want to benchmark the two.

I **do not** want this question to become one about the hardware.

This question is asking how I would test how good my hardware rates, for my software.

In other words, a 3D benchmark doesn't accurately rate my system for an ASP.NET/SQL Server app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the single best solution I've found for this problem is [Visual Studio Team Test Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts2008/test/default.aspx).  You can write your stress tests in whatever .NET language you like and its learnable and discoverable.  The metrics you get back from it are very informative.

There is a 90-day trial you may be able to get away with to see what I am talking about.  I had such a good experience at my previous company using it we just bought it outright at my present company and another developer who had never worked with it before had stress tests up and running within a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

After clarification, then I think you are looking for a **stress testing application**:

You can host your application on the two boxes, and then use another box to mass-send requests to it with a stress test app.

Then you can look at the statistics, e.g. Hits per seconds. Responses per second, etc.

I have never used one myself before but [Google knows some](http://www.google.co.th/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enTH291&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=asp.net+stress+test).

---

<strike>What do you mean? Could you clarify?</strike>

PCMark benchmarks the hardware, not the software.

Are you looking for a Profiler?

The company that build Resharper and Teamcity, [has one](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/).

It is a kind of software benchmark.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I think I clarified it. I'm looking to see how well the two hardware boxes rate, for the type of software I am using.

Answer (score 0):

I too have heard good things about VS test edition. However for testing of web apps, Jmeter  is a great free  tool, and quicker to get running.

http://jmeter.apache.org/